# why do i get Trying to get property of non-object when displaying my data?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am making a user profile, and I'm trying to display `TITRE_ANNONCE` in a select div but I get the error:

> Trying to get property of non-object

Here is my form:

```html
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <select class="contact_input" name="NOM_ARTICLE">
        @foreach($user as $annonce)
        <option> {{$annonce->TITRE_ANNONCE}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

with my controller :

```
public function voirprofile($id) {

    $user = DB::table('users')->
        join('article', 'article.id', '=', 'users.id')->
        join('annonce', 'annonce.ID_ARTICLE', '=', 'article.ID_ARTICLE')->
        where('users.id', $id)->
        get();

    return view('voirprofile') - > with('user', $user);
}
```

$user has user infos with all the 'annonce's he posted.
This is what $user returns:

```
[  
   {  
      "id":1,
      "name":"Othmane Messaoud",
      "email":"othmane.messaoud@gmail.com",
      "password":"$2y$10$at2J0teHoorwI7Y396Ckh.l1EvRojWJzomx4Ccqsf9LYA0j0oRxl.",
      "ville":"Rabat",
      "region":"Irfan",
      "ID_Ville":1,
      "tele_user":642213124,
      "type_user":0,
      "adresse":"Maroc, Rabat Al Irfan ENSIAS",
      "presentation":"je m'appelle othmane",
      "remember_token":"RPoRKcupcaBujbYoUj0e7QlmYaq0ybrhiKg3bHDwtQNK02DxLa7DPAi1QwsX",
      "created_at":"2019-03-30 13:56:06",
      "updated_at":"2019-03-30 13:56:06",
      "ID_ARTICLE":1,
      "TYPE_ARTICLE":"1",
      "NOM_ARTICLE":"Le maitre des illusions",
      "DESCRIPTION_ARTICLE":"ici la description de mon livre 'Le maitre des illusions' !!",
      "ID_ANNONCE":1,
      "TITRE_ANNONCE":"Annonce 1",
      "DATE_DEPOT":null,
      "TYPE_ANNONCE":"1",
      "PRIX":200,
      "ETAT_ANNONCE":1,
      "MOTIF_REFUS":null
   },
   {  
      "id":1,
      "name":"Othmane Messaoud",
      "email":"othmane.messaoud@gmail.com",
      "password":"$2y$10$at2J0teHoorwI7Y396Ckh.l1EvRojWJzomx4Ccqsf9LYA0j0oRxl.",
      "ville":"Rabat",
      "region":"Irfan",
      "ID_Ville":1,
      "tele_user":642213124,
      "type_user":0,
      "adresse":"Maroc, Rabat Al Irfan ENSIAS",
      "presentation":"je m'appelle othmane",
      "remember_token":"RPoRKcupcaBujbYoUj0e7QlmYaq0ybrhiKg3bHDwtQNK02DxLa7DPAi1QwsX",
      "created_at":"2019-04-09 15:39:30",
      "updated_at":"2019-04-09 15:39:30",
      "ID_ARTICLE":84,
      "TYPE_ARTICLE":"livre",
      "NOM_ARTICLE":"zednumber5",
      "DESCRIPTION_ARTICLE":"fsd",
      "ID_ANNONCE":26,
      "TITRE_ANNONCE":"voilae",
      "DATE_DEPOT":"2019-04-09 17:40:43",
      "TYPE_ANNONCE":"1",
      "PRIX":100,
      "ETAT_ANNONCE":1,
      "MOTIF_REFUS":null
   },
   {  
      "id":1,
      "name":"Othmane Messaoud",
      "email":"othmane.messaoud@gmail.com",
      "password":"$2y$10$at2J0teHoorwI7Y396Ckh.l1EvRojWJzomx4Ccqsf9LYA0j0oRxl.",
      "ville":"Rabat",
      "region":"Irfan",
      "ID_Ville":1,
      "tele_user":642213124,
      "type_user":0,
      "adresse":"Maroc, Rabat Al Irfan ENSIAS",
      "presentation":"je m'appelle othmane",
      "remember_token":"RPoRKcupcaBujbYoUj0e7QlmYaq0ybrhiKg3bHDwtQNK02DxLa7DPAi1QwsX",
      "created_at":"2019-04-09 14:57:05",
      "updated_at":"2019-04-09 14:57:05",
      "ID_ARTICLE":83,
      "TYPE_ARTICLE":"cahier",
      "NOM_ARTICLE":"besttestthatworks",
      "DESCRIPTION_ARTICLE":"sdfkljsdfkjl",
      "ID_ANNONCE":25,
      "TITRE_ANNONCE":"voila",
      "DATE_DEPOT":"2019-04-09 16:57:20",
      "TYPE_ANNONCE":"1",
      "PRIX":100,
      "ETAT_ANNONCE":1,
      "MOTIF_REFUS":null
   }
]
```

and it's correct data from my database.

When I add `{{dd($annonce)}}` after the loop :
[image]

[{{dd($user)}}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTHTb.png)

Comment: Can you just do {{dd($annonce)}} just after starting the for loop and show the output?

Comment: it shows somthing strange

Comment: Can you show it here or may be add to the question?

Comment: i just updated my post @akbansa

Comment: Can you just move this loop outside select and then do {{dd($annonce)}}?

Comment: i did and it shows  :  '1'

Comment: @foreach($user as $key => $annonce) 
    {{dd($annonce)}}
 @endforeach
And also try {{dd($user)}}?

Comment: Same result my man

Comment: try {{dd($user)}} only

Comment: its fetch one annonce but with all the attribute in the joins i did  cant type it all here i modify my post

Comment: maybe you can add a image

Comment: that what i was doing here it is post modified @akbansa

Comment: Im accepting your answer you helped me alot a learned new thing wth you thank you Mr @akbansa , i think i should move to next steps my project s still long

Comment: I have not written any answer for this

Comment: Yep i realised that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **optional** helper

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <select class="contact_input"  name="NOM_ARTICLE" >
        @foreach($user as $annonce)
           <option> {{optional($annonce)->TITRE_ANNONCE}}</option> 
         @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

Change
 {{$annonce->TITRE_ANNONCE}}
To
 {{optional($annonce)->TITRE_ANNONCE}}

Comment: it shows in my select {{optional($annonce)->TITRE_ANNONCE}}  times like its a string

Comment: just do <?php echo "<pre>"; print_r($annonce); die; ?> just after starting the for loop and show the output?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <select class="contact_input" name="NOM_ARTICLE">
        @foreach($user as $annonce)
            <option> {{$annonce['TITRE_ANNONCE']}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Illegal string offset 'TITRE_ANNONCE'